# Product reviews missing even on default theme

Tags: magento-1.9, review

We have a very strange problem.

We are not able to see the product reviews on the product page. Also the summary just below the product title with "write a review" is not showing up.

What I've done so far:

1. I've checked the module (Mage_Review) --> This is enabled
2. Switched to default magento theme to see if it's there (not visible)
3. Allow product reviews for guests --> Set to yes / no, not any difference
4. Added reviews on the backend --> Going OK
5. Checked the XML files and compared them with a fresh install.

It doesn't matter if you're logged in or logged out.

Comment: What about System > Configuration > Advanced? Is Mage_Review disabled under the Disable Modules Output section ?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism this is an answer, no comment :p

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt haha we'll see if it's one I'll post it as an answer if it fixes it ;)

Comment: Off course the module is enabled under advanced. Those things i've as the first fix. Unfortunatly without success :(

Answer (score 0):

If it is not the "Disable Module output" mentioned by Raphael, I would check for core hacks. Make sure the blocks are still in the layout xml file. If it is, add a breakpoint in the block and make sure the constructor is called. If there is no, add one ;-)

#### The block is called

If this is the case, make sure the template is found. (Your questions looks like you have read https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/429/217 if not, do).

#### The block is not called

When the block is not called, something is wrong in layout.xml, layout loading, rendering, etc. Make sure your code is untouched in the core.

Comment: The layout files are all unmodified. I will try to replace the core with the latest version.

Comment: I recommend digging into the code. xdebug is your friend

Comment: I'm not a really good programmer. Could you help me in the right direction?

Comment: I think then it is time to either get one or become one :)